# Should We Avoid the Use of LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am confused on an issue from last 7 days. I have googled a lot and also explored SO but could not find satisfactory answer.

I want to clarify my concept on LEFT JOIN. As we Know that LEFT JOIN returns All the Values from the LEFT Table and the Joined Values (through Foreign Keys) From the Right Table. Now, if There are (for example) 10 values in the Right Table pointing to a Primary Key in the LEFT Table, the LEFT JOIN will Repeat the First Table Values 10 Times while giving the Values from the Right Table.  It is just an example. Is it performance effective, OR Should I not be worried about it?

Here is an example of duplicate values

[image]

I have highlighted the duplicate values. 
Actually, I have a single table and I want to use the LEFT JOIN to get the child comments from the same table. And the Rows could be in 100s not in 1000s. I have indexes on the concerned fields.  So, Please guide me (Keeping in mind the native behavior of LEFT JOIN of giving the Repeated Rows From LEFT Table) that Should I be worried about it? and Is it mostly used or not?

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of trade-offs...

Firstly, does your outer join query perform well? Given the example you show, it should, if you're using indexed fields to map the foreign key relationship. Use EXPLAIN to find out if you are indeed using the indexed fields, and optimize the query if need be.

If the query itself is fast, the next concern is that you're sending slightly more data between your database and application server than you need to - the duplicated data from the left hand table. Whilst not ideal, I doubt you could measure the difference unless you really are working at HUGE volumes. If you're sending hundreds of records, with a few extra bytes per record, you have far bigger problems than the outer join if the network can't keep up.

Finally, you have to consider the alternative. With an outer join, you can retrieve all the matching data in a single query, even if it's slightly slower because of the join. The alternative would be to get all the parent records, loop through them and find the matching children. This would be far, far slower - instead of one query, you would be executing dozens or hundreds (based on your statement you're dealing with "hundreds, not thousands of records"). Each query has overhead, and put together that overhead is likely to be far more than the extra "join" statement cost.

However, the best way to find out is to use a tool like DBMonster, load up a test database with 10 times more data than you ever think you'll need, and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it performance effective, OR Should I not be worried about it?

This is a question that I can only direct back at yourself. Those questions are highly subjective only and can not be answered in a general fashion.

This is also the reason why you didn't find a simple answer on google about it.

The best answer I can give is: Get in contact with your database performance consultant and discuss the issue with her. She should be able to explicitly answer your questions after you've provided her enough information and access to a testbed.

Answer (score 0):

The most performant solution regarding bandwith would be to get the headers on one turn and get ALL children in a second turn. Keep them in memory and join them yourself. This is usually a "bad idea" since it doesn't scale well (imagine the memory requirements for multiple sessions on a single server all doing this on a dataset that keeps expanding), but if you can keep the dataset constant and the network really is that bad it's a viable option.

End answer: Yes, you understood it correctly. It's usually fine, but there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you describe is just how a left inner join works.

Do you have to use a left join to get the child comments? Is there another approach you could use? Perhaps (and this is totally off the cuff, with no research) use 1 query for the parent comment, a second for the child comments and union the results together?